# No other boot option than zorin

Tags: linux, boot, bios, zorin

I (pretty new to Linux) have installed the Zorin OS over my previously working Windows 10. Now I found out that the programs I need are not available for Linux, so I wanted to go back to Windows. However, when I wanted to do so I got myself a bootable USB for both Linux and Windows again to go for it. But I am not able to boot anything else than zorin. It seems everything is recognized but I can't change to USB or CD or anything else.

I also have no BIOS menu, which is very strange to me. I can press f2 (default key) on my fujitsu notebook but the only thing that appears is a menu with different zorin options (zorin and zorin with additional options).

Has anyone ever had this problems?

EDIT: 
This is what it says in my [boot options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpZWe.jpg), however, my [diagnostic screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L72q.jpg) says that the other devices are recognized and have higher boot priority.

Comment: you need to enter `setup` not boot menu to change the order in order to boot from usb.  If for some reason that  fails you boot zorin and at grub press 'c' and when presented with a prompt type" ` fwsetup` this should get you to the needed section of setup for changing the settings you need.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you did not screw up your motherboard somehow. There are some notebook-firmware combinations out there which can get bricked by installing Linux. Take out your hard drive and then start your notebook and try to get into the BIOS. If that works prepare a Windows-DVD (or USB), plug it in and start your notebook. If that works and you see the Windows-Setup, shutdown your notebook and connect the Hard Drive again. Power it on, open up BIOS and select the Windows-DVD (or USB) as First Boot Device and then restart. Then proceed with installing Windows.

Comment: I have tried that but only got to the boot menu. I edited my post so you can have a look. I also recognized that when I want to enter the BIOS screen, the screen is flickering before continuing a normal boot from the hard disk.

Comment: Did you try to boot without the HardDisk? If so and your USB (or DVD) is bootable then your Notebook should boot from that device. If that does not happen and you get a "Did not find a Boot device" or similar, then your USB (or DVD) is the problem. Also what do you get if you open the "Application Manager"?